# Oracle equivalent to MS-Access character range/set

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching

In MS-Access, I can use character ranges/sets in the where clause:

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM 
    all_tab_columns
WHERE
        table_name NOT LIKE 'A[0-9]*' 
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'D[0-9]*' 
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'S[0-9]*'
```

The character range/set is the range of numbers between 0-9. All tables that start with A, D or S, followed by a number, are eliminated from the query.

How can I do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php):

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM 
    all_tab_columns
WHERE
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(table_name,'^(A|D|S)[0-9]')
```

Comment: Careful, this is not the same. Your requirement is to exclude tables starting with `A` or  `D` or `S`, so this should be `^A[0-9]` and so on (where `^` marks the start of the line). It can be combined into a single expression: `^(A|D|S)[0-9]`.